# Replace Onclick prameters with a part of img src path

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi I am new to the world of Greasemonkey and JavaScript..

I want to replace every onclick function with a part of its related img src link

the source looks like this:

```
<div id="playlist_container">
                    <div id="video_container" onclick="playvid('a1a1a1a1a1',3201)" class="playing">
                <div id="thumbnail">
                                                <img src="https://.../thumb/ABCD.jpg">
                                            </div>
                <div id="title"></div>
                <div id="synopsis">
                    Vid 1                    </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
                    <div id="video_container" onclick="playvid('b2b2b2b2bb2',3202)" >
                <div id="thumbnail">
                                                <img src="https://.../thumb/EFGH.jpg">
                                            </div>
                <div id="title"></div>
                <div id="synopsis">
                    Vid 2                    </div>
            </div>
```

i want to replace the onclick 'playvid'  a1a1a1a1a1 & b2b2b2b2bb2 & c3c3c3c3c3c3 ... with part of img src link

to become like this:

```
<div id="playlist_container">
                    <div id="video_container" onclick="playvid('ABCD',3201)" class="playing">
                <div id="thumbnail">
                                                <img src="https://.../thumb/ABCD.jpg">
                                            </div>
                <div id="title"></div>
                <div id="synopsis">
                    Vid 1                    </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
                    <div id="video_container" onclick="playvid('EFGH',3202)" >
                <div id="thumbnail">
                                                <img src="https://.../thumb/EFGH.jpg">
                                            </div>
                <div id="title"></div>
                <div id="synopsis">
                    Vid 2                    </div>
            </div>
```

Here's what i've tried so far:

```
          var els = $("#playlist_container");
          var cod = $("div#thumbnail img").prop("src").replace(/(https(.+)\/thumb\/|.jpg)/gi, '');
          for(var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
          var el = els[i];
          el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/playvid(.)(.)(\w+)(.)/gi, "playvideo('" + cod +"'");
          }
```

this works for me but the issue is that it puts the first cod 'ABCD' to all the following 'playvid()' functions as shown below:

```
<div id="playlist_container">
                    <div id="video_container" onclick="playvid('ABCD',3201)" class="playing">
                <div id="thumbnail">
                                                <img src="https://.../thumb/ABCD.jpg">
                                            </div>
                <div id="title"></div>
                <div id="synopsis">
                    Vid 1                    </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
                    <div id="video_container" onclick="playvid('ABCD',3202)" >
                <div id="thumbnail">
                                                <img src="https://.../thumb/EFGH.jpg">
                                            </div>
                <div id="title"></div>
                <div id="synopsis">
                    Vid 2                    </div>
            </div>
```

another issue is when i try $("#video_container") it doesnt work i dont know why, I'm very confused and can't find anything on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html has duplicate ID values which can cause issues when finding the correct element. Try using class if you want to target multiple elements.

This code only gets the first element value

```
var cod = $("div#thumbnail img").prop("src").replace(/(https(.+)\/thumb\/|.jpg)/gi, '');
```

Try this code and let me know how it goes

```js
var images = $("div.thumbnail img");
      
images.each(function(img) {
  var name = $(this).prop("src").replace(/(https(.+)\/thumb\/|.jpg)/gi, '');
  var container = this.closest("div.video_container");
  var evt = $(container).attr("onclick").replace(/playvid(.)(.)(\w+)(.)/gi, "playvideo('" + name +"'");
  $(container).attr("onclick", evt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="playlist_container">
  <div class="video_container" onclick="playvid('a1a1a1a1a1',3201)" class="playing">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://.../thumb/ABCD.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="synopsis">Vid 1</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="video_container" onclick="playvid('b2b2b2b2bb2',3202)" >
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://.../thumb/EFGH.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="synopsis">Vid 2</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works but only when using ID changing $("div.thumbnail img") to $("div#thumbnail img") and closest("div.video_container") to closest("div#video_container"). dont know why i cant upvote your answer maybe i need to have more posts to do.. thank you again for the fast answer !!!